# How to make negated character class match containing characters once only (JS Regex)

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group, regex-negation

Am trying to use a negated character class to match the start of a URL `https://www.hyphen-site.com/`, in order to first confirm the given string contains a valid URL: `https://www.`. Estimated part of Regex: `[^https?:\/\/(www.)]`.

Having confirmed the validity of the URL using the negated character set, am trying to then return the actual site name part of the domain name: `hyphen-site` part of `hyphen-site.com`. Estimated part of Regex: `\w+-?\w+`.

This combined Regex: `/[^https?:\/\/(www.)]\w+-?\w+/gm` subsequently returns a string missing the first character, if that first character is part of the negated character class: `'yphen-site'`.

How would I go about restricting the negated character class to only matching its containing characters once, also kind of curious why it only matches the first character and not the characters following an (negatively) classified character.

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
    let regex = /[^https?:\/\/www.]\w+-?\w+/gm;
    let url = "https://www.hyphen-site.com/";
    let siteName = url.match(regex)[0]; // returns 'yphen-site' not required 'hyphen-site'
```

**Solved:**

Generic url site name extracting regex: (with and without "http(s)" & "www." & with zero or more "-")

`(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:w{3}\.)?([^\.]+)`

```
    let url = "w0skej3grhuyy5e-5k9vef29cgo-b.name";
    let regex = /(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:w{3}\.)?([^\.]+)/i;
    let output = url.match(regex)[1];
    output // returns "w0skej3grhuyy5e-5k9vef29cgo-b"
```

Comment: `[^(https)?:\/\/(www.)]` matches 1 character that is not `(, h, t, p, s, ), ?, :, /,w or .`

Comment: `/^https?:\/\/www\.(\w+(?:-\w+)?\.\w+)/.exec(url)[1]`